# Update SQL Server table to do this via a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update a SQL Server column with an auto-generated serial based on a `SELECT` date time ascend and also for based on a column with types.

Here is the algorithm on my mind:

```
1. To update a column AppNo  
update column_of_interest 
from_above_table 
auto_increment value (1..n)
where 
following datetime_col desc
2a. If Requesttype is AAA for a select where 
following datetime_col desc then there should be a different (1...n)
update
2b. If Requesttype is BBB for a select where 
following datetime_col desc then there should be a different (1...n)
update
3. The AppNo should reset each day, for each Requestype too.
```

For now my column of interest(AppNo) is null for now. 
I would like to update it like below:

```
ProjectID AppNo ProcessedDate
--------- ----- ----------------
       11     3 2019-09-30 18:21
        3     1 2019-09-25 08:37
        3     2 2019-09-25 08:37
       11     1 2019-09-25 08:39
       11     2 2019-09-25 08:40
        7     1 2019-09-26 14:19
        7     2 2019-09-26 14:20
        7     3 2019-09-26 14:22
        2     1 2019-09-26 14:23
       11     1 2019-09-26 14:23
       11     2 2019-09-26 14:24
       11     3 2019-09-26 14:24
        3     1 2019-09-26 14:24
```

I need to populate my column of interest based on the above.

Comment: You mention "computed column" but your code looks like it's updating a real column. It also has several words that are not standard SQL at all. Are you positive that your DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server? If so, and you've put some descriptive text into your query, could you insert comment lines so it's clearer what you want?

Comment: I said it is an algorithm and not sql server itself. My thoughts are expressed in form of an algorithm not really sql server.

Comment: The problem is that your question is not at all clear. What you should do is post the create statement for your existing table. Then explain clearly what you want to do. It seems like you want to add a new column? But what is the value for this new column?

Comment: I have edited the question, I do not know if it makes meaning now

Comment: @PeterGodfreyObike I have transcribed the data from the screen shot link as text into your question. Please avoid including images of data - it makes it harder for people to replicate your data so as to assist you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but I think you're looking for the [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) function, e.g.:

```sql
select
  foo,
  bar,
  baz,
  column_of_interest = row_number() over (order by datetime_col desc)
from above_table
```

This is not a computed column, per-se, since it's not part of the table schema, but should achieve the effect you are looking for.

Comment: You are close to what I want, but maybe because the question was not well put. Kindly see the edited question. Grateful

Comment: When you say "AppNo should reset each day" do you mean each day in wall clock time, or each day of some other `date` or `datetime` column in the table?

Comment: Each day in wall clock time, for every new day, the AppNo should begin again from (1....n) for each requesttype

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI0XM.png      That is the link to a kind of update for AppNo

Answer (score 0):

Every day morning, you can run below query to update all the records of previous day with proper Rownumber each day, for each request type.

```
;WITH CTE_TableToUpdate
(
SELECT ColumntoUpdate, DateOfUpdate, RequestType
Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY RequestType, DateOfUpdate ORDER BY DateOfUpdate) AS rn
FROM TableToUpdate
WHERE ColumnToUpdate IS NULL
AND DateOfUpdate < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)
UPDATE CTE_TableToUpdate
SET ColumnToUpdate = rn
```

Comment: Thank you very much, though I am yet to run your script. But for each entry, I would want the column value almost ready immediately for use.

Comment: It did not work, I checked the rn colums before the update and all I got was 1, 1, 1, for all rows. Please I need you to check you answer again